# Unable to shift equation numbers to right

Tags: equations, align, amsart

I am trying to LaTeX my old hand written notes. I am finding several glitches. Consider following code. How can I shift equation numbers to right. I used fleqn and align and flalign unsuccessfully. I am sure there is a short brief answer to this. I am pasting code without align and flalign tries.

```
\documentclass {amsart}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\newtheorem{Def}[]{Definition}

\begin{document} 
\begin{flushleft}\text{Real Number System The rational and irrantional numbers constitute the real number system.}\end{flushleft}
\begin{Def}
\underline{Rational Numbers:} a/b or p/q form: Numbers which are Quotient (Remainder) of two integers, with non zero denominator are called rational numbers e.g.,\begin{equation}\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{5},-3,-4 \end{equation}  etc.
\end{Def}
\begin{Def}
\underline{Irrational Numbers:}Those real numbers which are not rational are called irrational e.g., the numbers \begin{equation}\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3},e, \pi, e^{\pi}\end{equation}
\end{Def}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few points where you can improve your sample document.

1. `\text` should not be used in that context.
2. Instead of `flushleft` I suggest using a `\section` command for the header and standard text after it.
3. The text in definitions is usually printed upright, with the exception of the defined term, for which you can use `\emph`.
4. The `fleqn` option should be passed to the document class, because it automatically loads `amsmath` and passing `fleqn` to `mathtools` does nothing.
5. `a/b` and `p/q` are math formulas, so they should be segregated in `\(...\)` (or `$...$`, if you prefer) notwithstanding whether they appear in an italic context.
6. Underlining is a frowned upon typographic device.

The main point is however that `amsart` uses by default `leqno`, so it has to be overridden with the `reqno` option.

```
\documentclass[reqno,fleqn]{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{Def}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\section*{Real Number System}
The rational and irrational numbers constitute the real number system.

\begin{Def}
\emph{Rational Numbers}: $a/b$ or $p/q$ form: Numbers which are Quotient (Remainder)
of two integers, with non zero denominator are called rational numbers e.g.,
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{5},-3,-4
\end{equation}
etc.
\end{Def}

\begin{Def}
\emph{Irrational Numbers}: Those real numbers which are not rational are called
irrational e.g., the numbers
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3},e, \pi, e^{\pi}
\end{equation}
\end{Def}

\end{document}
```

Note that `amssymb` automatically loads `amsfonts` and that `amsthm` is incorporated into `amsart`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The default options in `amsart` are:

```
\ExecuteOptions{leqno,centertags,letterpaper,portrait,%
  10pt,twoside,onecolumn,final}
```

The `leqno` option makes left aligned equation numbers. If you use `\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}` it will do:

> [image]

I removed the `flushleft`, which is preventing the paragraph indentation.

Also, in text mode, the `\text` command does an `\mbox`, which prevents the line breaking in "number system".

You also have a typo in "irra**n**tional" and a missing space after `\underline{Irrational Numbers:}`.

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
\newtheorem{Def}[]{Definition}

\begin{document}
Real Number System The rational and irrational numbers constitute the real number system.
\begin{Def}
\underline{Rational Numbers:} a/b or p/q form: Numbers which are Quotient (Remainder) of two integers, with non zero denominator are called rational numbers e.g.,\begin{equation}\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{5},-3,-4 \end{equation} etc.
\end{Def}
\begin{Def}
\underline{Irrational Numbers:} Those real numbers which are not rational are called irrational e.g., the numbers \begin{equation}\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3},e, \pi, e^{\pi}\end{equation}
\end{Def}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\text` should be removed. And also `flushleft`, which seems used for avoiding the indent.